# Yet another NoClassDefFoundError puzzle

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I created two jar files, my.common.jar which contain helper classes and methods (mostly static methods). I also created a jar file, test.jar with a main method that calls a static method in a class in my.common.jar.

Everything works fine when I launch main like this:

```
java -classpath path/to/myjars/my.common.jar:./test.jar test.Tester
```

Tester is the class in test.jar that contains method main.

But I get `NoClassDefFoundError my/common/Myclass` when I run it this way:

```
java -classpath path/to/myjars/my.common.jar -jar test.jar
```

I tried so hard, but I am not able to figure out why it fails or how to resolve this issue. I do appreciate your help.

----- addendum ----
I forgot to mention that the manifest file in test.jar looks like so:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_13
    Created-By: Apache Maven
    Main-Class: test.Tester
    Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't defined the main class in the test.jar in the MANIFEST file.

Comment: For the second implementation to work. You need to specify the main class in `MANIFEST.MF` of jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use both `-classpath` and `-jar` options on the command line.  Use one or the other ... but not both.

When you use the `-jar` option, the command expects to find the entry point class AND the runtime classpath in the JAR file manifest.  Your `-classpath` argument will be ignored, as will the CLASSPATH environment variable.  To quote from the [`java` manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> "When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored."

If your (executable) JAR file needs to use things in other JARs, then it need a `Class-Path` attribute in the manifest.  This attributes value is a space separated list of URLs; see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes).

So in your case, you would need to add something like this to your JAR's manifest:

```
Class-path: /path/to/myjars/my.common.jar
```

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) of the Java Tutorial covers this topic, and includes the warning that the `Class-path` manifest line must be properly terminated with a CR or NL for the JVM to recognize it.

Comment: I had "export CLASSPATH=pth/to/myjars/my.common.jar" so as not to have -classpath on the command line. That also didn't work. Also, this is new information for me that I cannot use both -classpath and -jar together.

Comment: Thanks Stephen ... I added the class-path to the manifest file and now it works ... BUT I didn't have to do that before. I was running these programs under java 1.4.2, and now migrating to java 1.6. So I wonder why it worked fine under the older version but not the newer one??!!

Comment: @CJ - I can't explain why that is.  Perhaps someone has planted a copy of the `my.common.jar` file in the 1.4.2 Java installation's extensions directory. (Tsk, tsk, tsk)

Answer (score 0):

Put a manifest into the test.jar. The other jars normally go into a ./lib directory.
To add a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF to the jar, you normally can use the build infrastructure: ant or maven. Or do it manually.

You already have it with Main-Class: test.Tester.
Now Class-Path: ...

In Maven the dependencies are normally added to the the jar in the pom.xml. Your own jars you may put in your repository using mvn. And then add a dependency to it in the pom.xml.